# Return Count Grouped By Category With Item Containing That Category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table variable that contains entries like:

```
locationID locationIDsub codetype code       codeTitle
---------- ------------- -------- ---------- ---------------
24         15            08       000000     Scooters
51         15            08       000000     Scooters
51         15            08       110000     Trucks
24         15            08       110000     Trucks
51         15            08       111011     Semis
24         15            08       111011     Semis
24         15            08       119061     Dump Trucks
24         15            08       119071     Garbage Trucks
51         15            08       254011     Cars
```

What I want is this:

```
occcode    occtitle               count locationID
---------- ---------------------- ----- ---------
000000     Scooters               2     24,51
110000     Trucks                 2     24,51
111011     Semis                  2     24,51
119061     Dump Trucks            1     24
119071     Garbage Trucks         1     24
254011     Cars                   1     51
```

I am able to get the count just fine, just not able to get the count + list of locationIDs using the following:

```
SELECT Res.code,Res.codetitle,count(Res.codetitle)
FROM @resultsTable As Res
JOIN [dbo].[mv_VEHCODE_Union] As Veh
    ON Res.code= Veh.code AND Res.codetype = Veh.vehcodetype
GROUP BY Res.code,Res.codetitle
ORDER BY code
```

**Here is the final version** (still tweaking) I am going with based on Denis' answer (I dropped the count column since only used for the debugging):

```
select distinct 
    v.code, 
    v.codetype, 
    locations = stuff((
         select distinct ',' + cast(locationid as varchar) 
         from @resultsTable v2 
         where v2.code=v.code and v2.codetype = v.codetype 
         for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') 
    from @resultsTable v
    order by v.code
```

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Okay, looking at the example in the accepted answer I am still not seeing how to actually show the correct result. What I am getting is still 2 rows (one each for locationID) but the locationID list column has '24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,...' or '51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,...'. Essentially it has 1 locationID entry for each occurrence of the code value.

Comment: I actually went with http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/. However, performance is dog slow (as expected - but still needed to test it). We may have to pre-compile these code + locationList tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
select distinct 
v.code, 
v.codetype, 
cnt = (
     select count(*) 
     from mv_VEHCODE_Union v2 
     where v2.code=v.code and v2.codetype = v.codetype
), 
locations = stuff((
     select distinct ',' + cast(locationid as varchar) 
     from mv_VEHCODE_Union v2 
     where v2.code=v.code and v2.codetype = v.codetype 
     for xml path('')
),1,1,'') 
from mv_VEHCODE_Union v
order by v.code
```

Comment: The final FROM should be the @resultsTable, yes? If so, it still only returns one row per location.

Comment: then every table that I used should've been your table variable @resultsTable